# WPF add item to listbox, if the item doesn't already exist

Tags: c#, wpf

I am learning WPF and I came across the following problem:
I have one textbox (txbAuthor) and a listbox (lstAuthors), what I want to do is whenever semicolon is pressed I want the value in txbAuthor to be added in lstAuthors if the value doesn't already exist. I wrote this code, but it doesn't work:

```
private void Add_Author(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Key.P)
   {
   string Author = txbAuthor.Text.Remove(txbAuthor.Text.Length - 1);
   ListBoxItem itm = new ListBoxItem();
   itm.Content = Author;
   if (! lstAuthors.Items.Contains(itm))
   {
      lstAuthors.Items.Add(itm);
   }
      txbAuthor.Text = "";
  }
}
```

Also I in this code the KeyPress is being checked on "P" instead of semicolon, because I couldn't find semicolon in "Key." options, so I would also like to know how to check on semicolon press instead of "P".

Comment: you can use this line in a Textbox_TextChanged event to check for simicolon
            if ((sender as TextBox).Text[(sender as TextBox).Text.Length] == ';')
will not work in the keydown event!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
lstAuthors.Items.Contains(itm)
```

will always return `false` for a newly created `itm` object. But that doesn't matter, because your whole approach is wrong anyway.

---

In a WPF app you would usually implement the MVVM pattern and bind the ListBox's `ItemsSource` property to a string collection property in a view model class.

However, as a first step you could simply declare an `ObservableCollection<string>` member in your MainWindow class and in its constructor directly assign it to the ItemsSource property:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<string> authors
    = new ObservableCollection<string>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lstAuthors.ItemsSource = authors;
}
```

Now you would operate on that collection only:

```
var author = txbAuthor.Text.TrimEnd(' ', ';');

if (!authors.Contains(author))
{
    authors.Add(author);
}
```